# Split specified lines to multiple files

Tags: python-3.x

One format file with 100 lines, first 1-80 lines are common and 80-100 lines must be different sections (like each 5 lines having different set of information). From this format files need to create four different files with common line(1-80) and respective different section information.I need to use python for this task.
Below attached script is creating same lines to new files but i need to restrict based on lines and searchquery is the key for searching matching string or line to copy the respective section to new file and this function is still not working/found the required details.

Please let me know how to proceed this. Thanks in Advance.

```
format_file = 'file.format'
searchquery = 'IPv4_Active1' 

read_file = open(format_file,'r') 
   mvsip4222=read_file.read() 
   print(read_file.read())    # printing format file

wvs4_222 = 'file_ip4_active1.evn' # New files name 

new_file = open(wvs4_222,'w')   
   new_file.write(mvsip4222)    # writing format files lines to new file 

read_file.close() 
new_file.close()
```

Comment: Hope provided details are fine now!

Comment: Doesn't seem like the restriction is there. What have you tried so far? Also, what does the input and output looks like?

Comment: Below line from format file: 
```
<
Line1
Line2
Line3
###Section1
Line4
###Section2
Line5
###Section3
Line6      >
```
Right now same information getting copied to new file, with the below line able to control common lines copy to new file and but still am checking how to include common line alone with respective section(1,2...)

```
<
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines): #reading format file lines 
if i <= 2: # condition only copy 0-2 lines 
nf.write(line) 
>
```